# Images downloaded from firebase not scaling properly and not displaying until scroll on table view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

**What I want to happen:**

[image]

**What is actually happening:**

After building app, no images.

[image]

After scrolling, see images on cells below and when scroll up, see images on first cells.

[image]

**What I did: (Note: I'm doing everything programmatically. NO STORYBOARD)**

I loaded data from firebase database and firebase storage into `companies` (array of `Company` object that holds the name, location, and image). In the `cellAtRowAtIndexPath`, I assigned the cell's image to `companies[indexPath.row].image`.

**Company Table View Controller**

```
func loadData() {        
    databaseHandle = databaseRef?.child("companies").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                
                                //Get image
                let id = item.childSnapshot(forPath: "id").value as! String
                let imageName = id + ".png"
                let imageRef = self.storageRef?.child(imageName)
                imageRef?.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print((error as Error).localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        company.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }
                self.companies.append(company)
                self.companyTableView.reloadData()
            }
            
        })
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
    let company = companies[indexPath.row]
    let customCell = cell as! CompanyTableViewCell
      customCell.imageView?.image = company.image
      return customCell
}
```

**Company Table View Cell**

```
@IBOutlet weak var companyImage: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
          //Constraints set in .xib file. When tested, table view cell     
          properly displayed square images from assets folder
        companyImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

**Company Table View Cell xib**
[image]

**Memory issue:**
[image]

Comment: How are the constraints set in `CompanyTableViewCell.xib`? It seems like the width of the imageView is set extremely large, or you have the right constraint possibly pinned to the right of the superview? Can you share a snapshot of the xib in interface builder?

Comment: The width of the image view is set to 40 and the right constraint (company image.trailing) is 0 from left edge of the textView. Posted the xib in my question.

Comment: Shouldn't you be saying `customCell.companyImage.image = company.image` instead of `customCell.imageView?.image = company.image`? I think what you're doing is assigning the generic imageView inside `UITableViewCell`s that hasn't been customized with your `.xib`

Comment: Because the custom `UIImageView` in your cell is called `companyImage`

Comment: ohh i see! okay, I did that and the images look way better, but for some reason, it's still showing no images on the first section of cells until I scroll down and scroll back up

Comment: Look below. I posted an updated answer that should fix your problem. I hope it will anyways. I've noticed that sometimes with custom cells the `awakeFromNib` method doesn't always get called right away. Please let me know if my answer fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the `UIImageView` in your custom cell `CompanyTableViewCell` is `companyImage`, yet when you set the properties for your cell in `cellForRowAt(_:)` you are assigning the image for `cell.imageView?.image` instead of `cell.companyImage.image` which is your custom imageView that you set the constraints for. I think what you're doing is setting to image to the generic `UIImageView` in a `UITableViewCell` which is bounded by the cell, without any custom constraints.

To solve the scrolling problem, try creating a method inside your custom `CompanyTableViewCell` that looks like this:

```
func setupCell(image: UIImage) {
    self.companyImage.image = image
}
```

And then in your `cellForRowAt(_:)` method, instead of saying `cell.companyImage.image = company.image`, try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Initialize custom cell
    let company = companies[indexPath.row]
    let customCell = cell as! CompanyTableViewCell
    cell.setupCell(image: company.image)

    return cell
}
```

EDIT: Firebase issue

You want to make sure you never call any UI updates on a background thread. Also, from what I can tell it looks like in your Firebase method you are reloading the `UITableView` every time you go through the loop. This is seriously inefficient. You should call the `tableView.refresh()` method only after you've finished the loop and appended all your `company` values in the array.  Once that is finished then you should do an asynchronous call back, I think this will work, but I'm not a Firebase expert

```
func loadData() {
    databaseHandle = databaseRef?.child("companies").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            //Get image
            let id = item.childSnapshot(forPath: "id").value as! String
            let imageName = id + ".png"
            let imageRef = self.storageRef?.child(imageName)
            imageRef?.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print((error as Error).localizedDescription)
                } else if let data = data {
                    company.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
            self.companies.append(company)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.companyTableView.reloadData()
        }

    })
}
```

Just to be safe, change the `setupCell` method earlier to pass in an optional image, this should prevent any force-unwrapping nil images.

```
func setupCell(image: UIImage?) {
    self.companyImage.image = image
}
```

Comment: I tried the `setupCell` method, but I got "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I think it's because firebase is an asynchronous database, so company.image is nil for method calls (such as `print` and `setupCell`). Is there a way around this?

Comment: @15ongm - well you definitely need to do an asynchronous callback inside your Firebase method! You never want to do any UI execution on your background thread! Let me post an example. I will edit my answer

Comment: @15ongm - Please check my updated answer. See the recommended Firebase method changes for `loadData`, and also how I changed the `setupCell(image:)` method to pass in an optional `UIImage`.

Comment: I followed the code above. I tried `customCell.companyImage.image = company.image` and `customCell.setUpImage(image: company.image)`. For some reason, the issue is worse. After building thee app, at first, I see that the table is empty and then everything is shows up except the company image. I still need to scroll down and then back up for the first cells' company images to show up

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this helps, but when I'm running the app, the memory line continues to move to the right as added in my question.

Comment: How often are you calling `loadData()`? Do you call it more than once? And if so, do you ever clear the `companies` array?

Comment: No, I don't clear the `companies` array. `loadData()` is the last method to be called in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133129/discussion-between-pierce-and-15ongm).